# Difference between getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag and FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem

Tags: android, fragment

What's the difference between `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag` and `SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem` ?

I would like to call a method from Fragment, but when I'm using `(MyFragment) FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(0)` then the application throws `Exception` ( getActivity() 
into MyFragment returns null), But when I'm using `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(<tag>)` then all works good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ViewPager` then the `getItem` will simply return a new Fragment object or more precisely an instance of the a Fragment by the position given as input, while the `findFragmentByTag` method of `FragmentManager` will also return a Fragment object but it uses a tag String as parameter to identify the Fragment to be returned.